# MySQL Search query with like

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

i have database table with few text fields which i use to filter data , each of this text fields contain number data separated with colon ( for example '1:2:4:5:6:7:9' )

```
id   |  title         |  field1                 | filed2     | field3            |
1    | Some title1    |1:2:3:4:5:6:7            |1:2:3:6:7   | 1:2:4:5:7:9:10:11 | 
2    | Some title2    |1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:10:11  |1:2:3:4:5:6 | 1:2:4:5:7:9:10:11 |
3    | Some title3    |1:2:3:4:5:6:7            |1:2:3:6:9   | 1:2:4:5:7:9:10:11 |
4    | Some title4    |3:4:5:6:7:10:11          |1:2:3:10:11 | 1:2:4:5:7:9:10:11 |
5    | Some title5    |1:2:3:4:5:6:7            |1:2:3:6:7   | 1:2:4:5:7:8:9:11  |
6    | Some title6    |2:3:4:5:6:7:9            |1:2:3:6:7   | 1:2:4:5:7:9       |
```

using a search form i use check boxes for each parameters for field1, field2 and field3 and use php foreach to create LIKE '%`parameter`%' for each field

my SQL query look like
 `SELECT * FROM table WHERE (field1 LIKE '%1%' OR field LIKE '%2%' ) AND (field2 LIKE '%1%' OR field2 LIKE '%2%')`

unfortunately this query doesn't give me good result since i get back rows which doesn't match my idea :)

for example if checkboxes values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 are selected by user 
query need to return only 1, 3 and 5th row

is there any better solution for filtering this results

regards

Additional Info:

Let me try to explain you a little bit more the idea 
 User check chekboxes with some values (ie. 1,3,4,5,6,7) script need to return only results which contain those values in field1 same thing happens when user check other checkboxes which control field2 and field3 but for now it's not important

### Additional info pt2.

I'll try to give you all better explanation what i want to achieve

I have search form with checkboxes and radio input fields, each checkbox group ( values from 1 to 10 ) are represent columns ( field1, field2, field3 ) in table, each value in columns field1 for example represent selected checkboxes ( which are set in admin panel for each row ) now by default all check boxes are selected and i get all results now when user deselect respective checkbox results need to be filtered up with rows according to filter 
good example what i try to achieve is http://www.hotelscombined.com/City/London.htm

so if checkbox with value 2 is deselected it can't be listed in results

BR
Sile

Comment: Are you looking for exact match like field1 = '1:2:3:4:5:6:7' or do you want row #1 if the checkboxes are '2,3,4'?

Comment: I literally do not understand your question. Can you re-edit your question or rephrase it another way? You're saying `checkbox values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 query need to return only 1, 3 and 5th row`. Did the user select 1, 3, and 5th checkboxes?  Down vote for poor question construction.

Comment: yes when user check only checkboxes with values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

Comment: Maybe a SET-type column would make sense? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that `%1%` matches not only `1` but also `10`, `11`, etc.

It's better to do something like this:

```
WHERE CONCAT(':', field1, ':') LIKE '%:1:%'
```

Comment: when i use this in example `SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONCAT(':',field1,':') LIKE '%:1:%' OR CONCAT(':',field1,':') LIKE '%:3:%'` i get all rows as result maybe i didn't understand your point can you explain me this with sample

Comment: @Sile If your real data is the same as your sample then yes, this will return all 6 rows. I think you need to explain the logic you need better :)

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem since `1` can be the first character as in `1:2:3`. To go this route, you probably need a regexp, which means you might as well stick with the current format.

Comment: @Michael This should work very well when the first character is `1` :)

Comment: @Sile I guess that you need to return only those rows that have all of these checkboxes in field1, yes? If yes, then use **AND** operator, not **OR**.

Comment: @Karolis yes you are right i wont to get only rows that coresponds to selected checkboxes values and i don't want those which dont have this <br /> if selected checkbox values are 1,2,3,4,5,6 i need to get only rows 1, 2, 3, 5 and rows that need to be excluded are 4, 6 since they don't have value 1 in field1 column

Comment: @Sile So, use operator **AND**: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONCAT(':',field1,':') LIKE '%:1:%' AND CONCAT(':',field1,':') LIKE '%:3:%'`

Comment: @Karolis I use this query which you mention and i'm still getting result with values which isn't selected in my case using this sql `SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE 
( CONCAT (':',field1,':') LIKE '%:1:%' AND
CONCAT (':',field1,':') LIKE '%:2:%' AND
CONCAT (':',field1,':') LIKE '%:3:%' AND
CONCAT (':',field1,':') LIKE '%:7:%' ) AND 
(CONCAT (':',field2,':') LIKE '%:1:%' AND
CONCAT (':',field2,':') LIKE '%:3:%' AND
CONCAT (':',field2,':') LIKE '%:4:%' 
)` i get row 2 as result which is wrong since this row have in field1 `1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:10:11` but checkbox values (8, 9,10,11) aren't selected

Comment: @Karolis...I clearly wasn't paying attention to the colons you added at the beginning and the end. That's what I get for hopping on SO first thing in the morning ;)

Comment: @Sile According to your query, checkbox values for field1 are (1,2,3,7) and checkbox values for field2 are (1,3,4). So the second row is correct. I don't understand what is (8,9,10,11). I am unable to understand what logic do you need :)

Comment: @Karolis i'll try to give you better explanation and samples

Comment: @Sile Ok, I think I understood the main logic you actually need. In this case you can simply do this: `WHERE field1 = '1:2:3:4:5:6:7'`. You will just need to guarantee that the order of checkboxes is the same as in the database. If you cannot do this, then you may need to show us how are you implementing this in php.

Comment: Yes order of checkboxes is allways same ( it's only depends on filter group which represent columns filed1, filed2, filed3)

Comment: i'm on it currently but i neet to solve some php issues :), for now look promising

Answer (score 0):

As you see, field2 LIKE '%1%' will match field with value 2:10. To prevent this, add colon to end and beginning of string, and search for LIKE '%:1:%'
Other possible solution- adding colons to end and beginning in SQL
CONCAT(':',field2,':') LIKE '%:1:%'

Other way is to refactor your database to something like

```
main_table
id   |title
1    |some title

link_table
main_id|field|value
1      |f1   |1     
1      |f1   |2     
1      |f2   |2     
1      |f3   |1     
1      |f3   |2
```

and to make query to get data

```
select id,title from main_table
join link_table on main_table.id=link_table.main_id
where (field = 'f1' and value in (1,2)) or (field = 'f2' and value in (2,3))
```

as result, if you're using your current database design, if you need to get all rows, that have set of "1,2,3,4,5,6,7" in field 1, you'll need to make a query like

```
WHERE CONCAT(':',field1,':') LIKE '%:1:%' OR  
CONCAT(':',field1,':') LIKE '%:2:%' OR 
CONCAT(':',field1,':') LIKE '%:3:%' OR
CONCAT(':',field1,':') LIKE '%:4:%' OR
CONCAT(':',field1,':') LIKE '%:5:%' OR
CONCAT(':',field1,':') LIKE '%:6:%' OR
CONCAT(':',field1,':') LIKE '%:7:%'
```

If you'll refactor as I say, query will be like

```
where field = 'f1' and value in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
```

and much faster

Answer (score 0):

Use AND in instead of OR:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (field1 LIKE '%1%' AND field LIKE '%2%' ) AND (field2 LIKE '%1%' AND field2 LIKE '%2%')
```